# R: Break a data.frame according to value of column with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have this data.frame

```
MWE <- data.frame(x = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), y = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

and what I want to obtain is this data.frame

```
data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6))
```

Actually, what I originally want is to `sum` the 2 vectors `a` and `b` (well, I have in reality many more vectors, but it is easier to explain with only 2), so that's why I thought about this transformation. I can do a `rowSums` then, or something equivalent.

I tried to use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr` but I had an error.

Any idea of how to do this with `dplyr` or `tidyr`?

Comment: Actually it sounds like you really just want `MWE %>% group_by(x) %>% summarize(sum=sum(y))`

Comment: `MWE_list <- MWE%>%group_split(x)` from `dplyr`. This will safe both groups as seperate dataframes in a list.

Comment: Well, it's a bit trick to match up `a` and `b` values in your example since there is no ID. But something like `MWE%>%group_by(x) %>% mutate(i=row_number()) %>% pivot_wider(id_cols=i, names_from=x, values_from=y) %>% select(-i)` would give that intermediate result.

Comment: @MrFlick well, what I'd like is to obtain the new vector `a+b = (5,7,9)`, so sum by lines. Your solution is the sum by `x`, will return `a 6` and `b 15`.

Comment: @JohannesStötzer I saw that solution, but I want to keep in just one data.frame

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you, your last solution works well! I understand the error now, because there was no ID. And if you have a direct solution to compute the sum as indicated, I'd love to see it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from @Mr.Flick's attempt in `tidyverse` you could create an id column and grouped on that id column calculate the sum like

```
library(dplyr)

MWE %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(total_sum = sum(y)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = x, values_from = y) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-row)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  total_sum     a     b
#      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1         5     1     4
#2         7     2     5
#3         9     3     6
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `unstack` from `base R`

```
unstack(MWE, y ~ x)
#  a b
#1 1 4
#2 2 5
#3 3 6
```

---

Or using `rowid` from `data.table` with `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
MWE %>% 
   mutate(rn = rowid(x)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = x, values_from = y) %>%
   select(-rn)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#      a     b
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     4
#2     2     5
#3     3     6
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R:

```
data.frame(with(MWE, split(y, x)))

  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

Comment: Thank you @sindri_baldur ! Do you know how to do this with tidyverse too? Btw, I tried to compute the code in my question and didn't succeed. How did you do it?